# FK to same table using nullable Id's

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

```
public class Email
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    /// ...
    public int? ReplyTo { get; set; }
    public int? ForwardOf { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to configure `ReplyTo` and `ForwardOf` to be FK to `Email.Id` property with cascade Delete.

Tried this:
`e.HasOne(nameof(Email.ReplyTo)).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);`

but it gives an error

`` The specified type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' must be a non-interface reference type to be used as an entity type. ``
I would prefer not to have navigation properties of type `Email` as they will never be used by my code.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `int?` with `Email` so that EF can build the FK itself? I usually do similar things to this in that way: `public class Package { public int Id { get; set; } public Package Parent { get; set; } }` This way if there's no related item the FK value in the db will just be a 0. I think you can still cascade delete in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should allow a shadow navigation property:

```
.HasOne<Email>()
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReplyTo)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehaviour.Cascade);
```

Though I'm not sure you'd want a delete cascade on such a relationship.